# How to preload UISearchDisplayController with a search string

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to preload UISearchBar with a searchString.

In the current set up. I'm using UISearchDisplayController in the UITableViewController.

**The First approach** I use is set the search string in the following method:

```
- (void) presetSearchDisplayControllerWithString:(NSString*)searchString{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:NO];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    self.searchBar.text = searchString;
    self.searchFetchedResultsController = [self   createFetchedResultsControllerWithSearchTerm:searchString];
}
```

It works. UISearchbar shows the search string, original tableView and TableViewIndex are hidden. But if I press cancel button on the searchBar it crashes:

* Assertion failure in -[UISearchDisplayController setActive:animated:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UISearchDisplayController.m:682
 *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'search contents navigation controller must not change between -setActive:YES and -setActive:NO'**

The Second varian is not working either

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:@"rune"];
}
```

Well, it works if you tap in the searchbar. But until you've done it, it shows just a regular tableView.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: No. I ended up not using searchDisplayController. Not sure, but I think I tried your combination as well, and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (only based on the exception raised):

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];
self.searchBar.text = searchString;
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:NO];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
self.searchFetchedResultsController = [self createFetchedResultsControllerWithSearchTerm:searchString];
```